# Creating Extension method of 'Any' Type. Error: 'Any' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here

Tags: angular, typescript, extension-methods

I want to create extension method that of ANY type that takes string or number if It is NAN or NULL convert it to empty string But getting this error .

```
declare global {
    interface Any {
        NullToEmptyString(): any;
    }
}

Any.prototype.NullToEmptyString = function (): any{ <--- Here is error
    return this == null ? '' : this;
}
```

Comment: `Any` is not a thing that exists at runtime. You can likely add it to `Object`. With that said, adding methods to global objects is generally a bad idea and to be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

`any` is purely a type, it doesn't actually exist outside of the type system. And you can't add methods to `null` anyway, it will just cause an exception. You should make a method that takes in an `any` argument:

```
function nullToEmptyString(arg: any): any {
    return arg == null ? '' : arg;
}
```

Comment: This function can just be replaced with the nullish coalescing operator `x ?? ''`

Comment: That's true @VLAZ

Comment: This gives me compiler error my angular version is 8.3.25

Answer (score 0):

`interface` definition from https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html :

> One of TypeScript’s core principles is that type checking focuses on
> the shape that values have. This is sometimes called “duck typing” or
> “structural subtyping”. In TypeScript, interfaces fill the role of
> naming these types, and are a powerful way of defining contracts
> within your code as well as contracts with code outside of your
> project.

and, interface are not compiling to the `javascript` side of your typescript file.

for example:

```
interface Hello {

}

class Hello2 {

}
```

transpile to:

```
var Hello2 = /** @class */ (function () {
    function Hello2() {
    }
    return Hello2;
}());
```

so for making your code work, you need to use a class instead of interface (but it may not achieve your other goals):

```
export { };

declare global {
    class Any {
        NullToEmptyString(): any;
    }
}

Any.prototype.NullToEmptyString = function (): any {
    return this == null ? '' : this;
}
```

wich transpiles to:

```
"use strict";
exports.__esModule = true;
Any.prototype.NullToEmptyString = function () {
    return this == null ? '' : this;
};
```

Comment: A class inside a `declare` doesn't actually create a runtime class but just add it to the ambient context, so that code will throw a runtime error. Overall, the entire approach from OP is incorrect, as it seems they want to manipulate compile-time types at runtime.